# Converting table strings to datenum

Tags: matlab, datetime, matlab-table

I have Matlab table with strings and I would like to convert it to the datenum format. I tried:

```
datenum(Tbl)
```

but I received the error:

```
Error using datenum (line 181)
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using datevec (line 103)
    The input to DATEVEC was not an array of character vectors.
```

Here is a sample of my Tbl:

```
Tbl = table;
Tbl.('A') = {'29/07/2017'; 0};
Tbl.('B') = {'29/07/2017'; '31/07/2017'};
```

Comment: Added Tbl example.

Comment: Added Tbl as a text.

Comment: How did you get `0` into a table of strings?

Comment: From Import it added it @excaza

Answer (score 2):

Try [varfun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varfun.html):

```
varfun(@datenum,Tbl)
```

to produce

```
datenum_A    datenum_B
_________    _________

12791        12791    
    0        13521
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively, can do them one column at a time like this:

```
Tbl.('A') = cellfun(@datenum,Tbl.('A'))
```

to produce

Tbl =

```
  A           B      
_____    ____________

12791    '29/07/2017'
    0    '31/07/2017'
```

Then you can do it for 'B', etc.

Answer (score 1):

Convert [table to an array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table2array.html) first and then apply [`datenum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) alongwith the format of date. Inclusion of numbers in your data is weird but, anyway, here is a solution:

```
numdate= table2array(Tbl);       %Converting table to array
ind = cellfun(@ischar,numdate);  %Finding logical indices of dates stored as char array
%Finding serial date number of dates; not doing anything on numeric values
numdate(ind)=cellfun(@(x) datenum(x, 'dd/mm/yyyy'), numdate(ind),'un',0); %Serial Datenums
%Converting back the date number serials into dates    
dateback=numdate; dateback(ind)=cellfun(@datestr,numdate(ind),'un',0);
```

**Output:**

```
>> numdate

numdate =     
    [736905]    [736905]
    [     0]    [736907]

>> dateback

dateback =
    '29-Jul-2017'    '29-Jul-2017'
    [          0]    '31-Jul-2017'
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I do datestr(...) I get the wrong dates. So it did not work.